# How to execute a stored procedure that returns variable number of columns in EF 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is there any way I can execute a stored procedure using EF 6 that can somehow handle variable number of columns returned? I am doing a dynamic pivot in the stored procedure (converting row values to columns) and so, the number of columns returned varies based on an input id to the procedure. So, it is not known at compile time for me to declare properties in strongly typed POCO classes.

I also tried using other constructors of `SqlQuery` and I just couldn't figure out how to get the results back.

Thanks

Comment: That honestly sounds more like something you'd handle through Dapper.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I LOVE Dapper. But here unfortunately its an EF shop.

Comment: No laws against using both, with Dapper filling in the cracks that EF doesn't properly cover. Unless your company actually does have a law, in which case I can only pull out that old adage: "a foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of a small mind". The obvious alternative would be to make the pivot static, or else not pivot at all but supply the data in row form, aggregating it (or rather pivoting it) on the client side instead -- the latter could be done quite comfortably with EF and LINQ to Objects.

Comment: would `dynamic` and raw SQL queries with EF help you out? EF does support raw queries :) 

OTherwise, you can look into just using a raw SqlConnection or something like that..

And otherwise i would say... use the best technology for the job. If Dapper is the best one, just talk to the team about it? If you are gonna either write that query and execute it with EF or write it and execute it with Dapper (with cleaner code), why refuse dapper? It's basically the same thing at that point! :)

Comment: Yeah, I finally went for that. I will paste the solution here once I am done testing. Thanks !

Comment: @JeroenMostert, If not Dapper,  I could certainly  use that quote from here on:-). Yeah, unfortunately the Static PIVOT is ruled out, as the users are very fastidious about the format.

Answer (score 0):

I finally did this.

```
var param = new SqlParameter[] {
    new SqlParameter() {
        ParameterName = "ID",
        SqlDbType =  System.Data.SqlDbType.BigInt,
        Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
        Value = someid
    }};
    
var context = new SystemDBContext();

using (var cnn = context.Database.Connection)
{
    var cmm = cnn.CreateCommand();
    cmm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmm.CommandText = "[dbo].[SPName]";
    cmm.Parameters.AddRange(param);
    cmm.Connection = cnn;
    cnn.Open();
    var reader = cmm.ExecuteReader();

    var list = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(reader.GetName).ToList();
    int colCount = reader.FieldCount;

    while (reader.Read())
    {   
        for (var counter = 0; counter <colCount; counter++)
        {
            //do whatever`
        }           
    }       
}
```